# How to add LinearLayout in RelativeLayout , where dynamic contents loaded in Relativelayout from DB?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

How to add LinearLayout in RelativeLayout , where dynamic contents loaded in Relativelayout from DB? I want button to be loaded at the end of page. Text & Image loaded as number of rows from DB.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rowLayout"  android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"> 



<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/profileImg"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="4px"  android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:src="@drawable/checkmark" >
</ImageView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/origin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="20dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
</TextView>`</LinearLayout> <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">`

   <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"  android:text="ADD POOL" android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:background="#ff9b0c" android:onClick="serviceMessage"  />
</LinearLayout>    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my answer. You can add new row to contentLayout with new LinearLayout like rowLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rowLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileImg"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14px"
            android:layout_marginRight="10px"
            android:layout_marginTop="4px"
            android:src="@drawable/checkmark" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/origin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@+id/label"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/contentLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ff9b0c"
    android:onClick="serviceMessage"
    android:text="ADD POOL"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks @Danh, it changed the format where button is visible. I want button once in the end of page where it is coming as per the rows displayed.

Comment: you can use ScrollView is parent of ContentLayout :)